# NodeJS, express, browser não encontra arquivos

Tags: node.js, react

Boa tarde pessoal, fiz uma API com Node e a consumi com o React, em ambiente de desenvolvimento, funciona OK porque início uma independente da outra, mas em produção estou tentando entregar os arquivos estáticos compilados pelo React para o Node, são 3 arquivos. Um HTML, um CSS e um JS. O HTML está sendo entregue perfeitamente, no entanto, o JS e o CSS não parecem estarem OKs.

No caso, o HTML está sendo entregue pois o title e o icon estão funcionando, mas a  tela fica branca e no console aparece a seguinte mensagem: "**Falha no carregamento do  com a fonte “http://biodinamicahc.com.br/app.js**"

No caso, estou entregando a pasta public da segunte forma:

```
if (process.env.PRODUCTION) {
    app.set('public', path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public'));
    app.use(express.static(app.get('public')));
}
```

Para quando a rota "/" for acessada, ele jogar os demais arquivos juntos.

```
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
        if (process.env.PRODUCTION) {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../public/index.html'));
        } else {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'API rodando em ambiente de desenvolvimento!'
            })
        }

    });
```

Tentei jogar os arquivos estáticos de JS e CSS juntos no "res.sendFile", mas não funcionou, a mensagem continuou. Alguém saberia me dizer o que possa ser?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando `express`

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Suponhamos que tenho estas pastas

```
/
  /server.js
  /public
    /css
      /style.css
    /js
      /index.js
  /index.html
```

Dentro de `/index.html` faça isso

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"></link>
```

Repare que eu não coloquei `/public/css/style.css`

O express interpreta a `/public` como se fosse o root da aplicação no browser.